# Spotify oEmbed API stopped working

Tags: ruby, api, spotify, oembed

Until recently, I could query the Spotify oEmbed API for an embed snippet by requesting `https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/?url=<track_url>&format=json`

Since then, it still works in the browser or via `wget`, but it does not work anymore programmatically via e.g. Ruby:

`Net::HTTP.get_response(oembed_url)`

This now returns a blank string and 200 Status Code (success). What changed? Does it need specific HTTP headers?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, it requires a User Agent. I guess this is a pretty standard practice but a tiny tweet from @SpotifyPlatform would have been appreciated.

Be careful not to use a nondescript user agent like e.g. `Ruby` but rather something specific like the name of your app to avoid running into quota limitations.